# \tiny can't change the font size of the symbol such as \sum in equation

Tags: fonts, equations

I want to change the font size of the equation, but it seems that the large symbol in equation such as `\sum` can't be changed. Why would that happen ?

This is my **AWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\tiny\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]

{\Large\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}

{\LARGE\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\end{document}
```

and this is my outcome:[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar While what you say is true, it still doesn't answer the question as to why `\sum` does not fix itself to the current font size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\sum` is defined using the `largesymbols` maths symbol font:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}
```

This symbol font is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
```

Examining the contents of `omxcmex.fd`, we find this:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{cmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*cmex10%
   }{}
```

`sfixed` is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareSizeFunction{sfixed}{\fixed@sfcnt\@font@info}
```

We also have:

```
\def\fixed@sfcnt#1{%
  \ifx\optional@arg\@empty
    \let\external@font\mandatory@arg
  \else
    \edef\external@font{\mandatory@arg\space at\optional@arg pt}%
  \fi
  #1{External\space font\space `\external@font'\space loaded\space
     for\space size\MessageBreak
     <\f@size>}%
}
```

and `\@font@info` is, I *think*, fetching general information about a font.

So I *think* that

```
   <->sfixed*cmex10%
```

is essentially loading `cmex10` at its natural size.

Hence, the symbol font `largesymbols` uses a font of fixed size i.e. it is not scaled and no discrete variations in size are available either. Therefore, any symbol which is defined in terms of this particular symbol font, including `\sum`, will have a fixed size.

Although loading `amsmath` is a good idea (`mathtools` would be even better), it is not necessary to do so to address this particular issue. The reason loading `amsmath` solves the problem is because, by default, `amsmath` sets up the extended fonts from AMS. Basic support for these is also provided by `amsfonts.sty` which includes the following:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
       <-7.5>cmex7%
    <7.5-8.5>cmex8%
    <8.5-9.5>cmex9%
    <9.5->cmex10%
}{}%

\expandafter\let\csname OMX/cmex/m/n/10\endcsname\relax
```

This essentially means that we now have variable sizes available for symbols defined in terms of `largesymbols`. Hence, loading `amsfonts` alone is sufficient to get a `\sum` which scales with the current font size:

[image: variable sized <code>largesymbols</code> with <code>amsfonts</code>]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\meaning\sum
{\tiny\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]

{\Large\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}

{\LARGE\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure why your MWE exhibits the behavior, it can be fixed by invoking `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

{\tiny\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]

{\Large\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}

{\LARGE\[A_{j}(\vec(t)_{j})=exp(\gamma_{j}||\vec{t}_{j}||^{4}),S_{MV}(\vec{r})=\sum_{j}A_{j}(\vec{t}_{j}),\gamma_{j}=\frac{\gamma_{0}In(\lambda)}{R_{j}^{4}}\]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would note that in the OP's code, the `\meaning` of `\sum` is

```
\mathchar"1350
```

whereas, once `amsmath` is loaded, the `\meaning` is

```
macro:->\DOTSB \sum@ \slimits@
```

Comment: `\sum` is defined in terms of `largesymbolx`, whereas the rest is using the alphabet `letters`, which is sensitive to the current font size. Am I missing the nature of the puzzle here?

Comment: @cfr I don't know the ins and outs of how symbols get defined, but I know that the MWE posted by the OP was not behaving as one would expect LaTeX to behave.

Comment: I think it is just because `amsmath` loads `amsfonts` and everyone is so used to using `amsmath` that this seems just 'LaTeX'.

Comment: What you say about the `\meaning` is true but I don't see that it is relevant to the problem. However, I admit that I don't understand this at all well. Could you explain why that code would make a difference? Note that this code is certainly not *necessary* because it is possible to get a variable sized `\sum` without changing its `\meaning`.

Comment: @cfr My only point in looking at the meanings was to note that `amsmath` in some way redefined what `\sum` was.  As I said, I don't understand all the intricacies of how that is done and what it means, other than, in this case, it fixed it.

Comment: All I meant was that I don't think the change in `\meaning` is relevant to the fix. It is the redeclaration of the font family which does the fixing.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `amsmath` loads `amsfonts`. It just does similar font set up directly. But it is the redeclaration of the font family which does the fix, I think.